# Pointer to Array throwing errors when I try to assign an index to nullptr

Tags: c++, c++17

Class:

```
template <class T>
class vectorADT
{
public:
//default constructor
vectorADT();
//destructor
~vectorADT();

//push data to the front of the vector
void push_front(T data);
//push data to the rear of the vector
void push_back(T value);
void insert(int position, T value);
//remove data from the front of the vector
void remove_front();
//remove data from the rear of the vector
void remove_rear();
//return the front of the vector
T getFront();
//return the rear of the vector
T getRear();
//check if vector is full
bool isFull();
//create a new vector with more space
T *resize(T *prevSizePtr);
//return the size of the vector
int size();
//check if the vector is empty
bool isEmpty();
//print the vectors data
void print();

private:
T *vectPtr;
T array[4] = {};
int front;
int rear;
int vectSize;
};
```

constructor:

```
template <class T>
vectorADT<T>::vectorADT()
{
front = 0;
rear = -1;
vectSize = 4;
vectPtr = array;
}
```

Class Method:

```
template <class T>
void vectorADT<T>::push_front(T data)
{
if (vectPtr[0] == nullptr)
{
    vectPtr[front] = data;
}

front++;
}
```

I asked a question earlier but I am still really confused on how this works. I want to be able to check if my array has nullptr as a value, that way I know whether that index is empty, and if it is, I can assign that index some data. Whenever I try to make the comparison to nullptr, I get a host of errors about operator==. I thought that when I do T array[4] = {} it would initialize all the index to nullptr or zero, thus making it valid to compare that index with nullptr, however that obviously is not the case. If anyone could point me in the right direction on how I would go about doing something like that I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Is `T` always a pointer type? If not, then you can't just compare other things to nullptr.

Comment: @arcticsanto Sorry about that. We collided on a simultaneous edit. Re-propose your edit and I'll help push it through.

Comment: T data being passed into push_front would be string and int. Would this work without templates? And how would you do something like this with templates?

Comment: If `T` is non-array/pointer type, then `vectPtr[0]` is type `T` not `T*` (so `nullptr` doesn't make sense) It would if `T` were an array or pointer type.

Comment: If the vector should only contain pointers, you should make it `T **vectPtr;`

Comment: But then it will also need to be `push_front(T *data)`

Comment: Your mistake is thinking that there is some kind of magic 'empty' value that works for all types, like nullptr, but there isn't. So think about how can tell whether your vector is full without using such a magic value.

Comment: Right, C++ isn't like JavaScript, PHP, Python which have a general-purpose `null` or `None` value.

Answer (score 1):

Re: `I want to be able to check if my array has nullptr as a value, that way I know whether that index is empty` - You really don't need to know that. You should maintain a `size` of your vector that would tell you if there are available slots and where they are. What you call `vectSize` is in fact its `capacity`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin this appears (to me) to be an exercise in programming a `vector` class

Comment: yea its a program for a circular queue